# Photoshop Actions - Is this possible?

Tags: photoshop, photoshop-script, photoshop-cs5

Okay, here's what's going on..
I have a folder that has 200 images in it.
They're all named - p001.png, p002.png, p003.png... all the way up to p200.png

I need to create an Action that pulls in 2 images at a time, in ascending order.

After Resizing & Positioning the images, I need to add text above each image that says "Image #X"
(in place of 'X', would be the number of the corresponding image)

Once it finishes with the 1st two images, it saves it in a specified folder; and pulls in the next 2 images.

And just repeats the process until it goes through all 200 images.

**Here's my 2 questions:**

1 - Is it possible to pull in 2 images at a time in ascending order, from a specified folder, via an Action?

2 - Is it possible to replace 'X' with the image's number, as it moves up in ascending order?

Any kind of help with this would be Greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

*p.s. I'm using PhotoShop cs5.5 if that makes a difference*

Comment: Are you on OSX or Windows? How do we work out the name of the specified folder? How do we resize and position the images? Do they get added to a common canvas or do two images get saved in the specified folder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First checkout the [Contact Sheet functionality](https://helpx.adobe.com/photoshop/using/contact-sheet-pdf-presentation-cs6.html), perhaps you can achieve your tasks this way.

In terms of scripting, there are indeed functions available to :

- load a file into the document
- create a text layer
- set the text of the text layer

Check out the [Photoshop CS5 JavaScript Language Reference](http://www.aselsan.com.tr/tr-tr/iletisim/destek/Documents/Driver/Photoshop%20CS5%20JavaScript%20Ref.pdf) for more details.
Additionally, you should have [Extend Script Toolkit](http://www.adobe.com/uk/products/extendscript-toolkit.html) installed as well.

Run Extend Script Toolkit then give this a quick go:

```
#target photoshop
alert("Hello World!");
```

Using the **Object Model Viewer** (available under the Help menu) you should be able to select the Photoshop Type Library and view useful available objects such as `Application,Document,Layer`, etc. and see their properties and methods.
Additionally the `Data Browser` panel and autocomplete should help.

Comment: Alright, well that whole scripting thing is a bit over my head, lol.

Comment: But, I did find this pre-built script at http://blogs.adobe.com/jkost/2010/09/add-file-name-as-text-layer.html , That uses the File Name to add a Text Layer.. So I just renamed all of my files (with the batch process) to the text that's needed for each image. So that solves my 2nd question. -- And I'm now working on a solution for my 1st question.. Anywho, thanks for the suggestions George Profenza. Looking into all of that scripting stuff, is actually what led me into finding that pre-build script :p

Comment: The way the question was phrased I understood you're looking into how to write such a script yourself (which sounds like the right way to get into Photoshop scripting). Using an existing script then understanding it/tweaking it is another good way to learn too ! Feel free to vote/mark the answer if it was helpful ;) Have fun!